# Ubuntu bc weird behavior

Tags: 14.04, bash, 16.04, awk, bc

There is a weird behavior in Bash script. Trying to run following lines in two different systems.

**Script:**

```
cpuIdle=$(mpstat 5 1 | grep Average | awk '{  print $12 }')
cpuUsage=$(bc <<< "100.0-$cpuIdle")
```

And here are the details of machines.

**System-1:**

- Ubuntu 14.04.04 LTS
- `Linux 4.2.0-36-generic #42~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 13 17:27:22 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- `awk --version` = `GNU Awk 4.0.1`
- `bash --version` = `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

**System-2:**

- Ubuntu 16.04.04 LTS
- `Linux 4.4.0-22-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 12 22:03:46 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- `awk --version` = `GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)`
- `bash --version` = `GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Script runs fluently on System-1 but gives following error on **System-2** while running `bc`:

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

I can confirm that in both systems **cpuIdle** vairable is being set correctly (*1st line of the scrip*t).

I also can confirm that bc working without a problem in both systems when I set **cpuIdle** variable manually (*like cpuIdle=97.3*).

Can't decide if this is a bug or my mistake. Any suggestion or ideas?

Comment: You might want to look at `mpstat`'s output.

Comment: Already looked it. I did not see any differences.

Comment: it is the comma so probably a language issue?

Comment: Are you sure? I'd bet that `cpuIdle` is empty or an invalid number. Tried echoing `cpuIdle`?

Comment: @muru thx for the comment but Rinzwid found the problem. I was editing my question according to your suggestions before I got the answer.

Comment: @muru you should have posted it as an answer >:-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the comma.

```
$ cpuIdle=$(mpstat 5 1 | grep Average | awk '{  print $12 }')
$ echo $cpuIdle
99,25
```

->

```
$ cpuUsage=$(bc <<< "100.0-95,25")
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

and

```
$ cpuUsage=$(bc <<< "100.0-95.25")
$ echo $cpuUsage
4.75
```

---

So this could be an internationalization issue (in Holland we use a comma for decimals). I would say: bug, someone forgot to include a comma as a possible decimal sign.

Switch to American annotation and it will work again.

Comment: Yep that's correct. It was comma. It must be bug as you suggested.

Comment: @bensen not a bug (at least as far as the devs are concerned). It's in the manpage:        LANG environment
              This version does not conform  to  the  POSIX  standard  in  the
              processing  of the LANG environment variable and all environment
              variables starting with LC_.

Comment: do not know. actually I've been applying same settings to my fresh installs since 12.10. living in Turkey but never set anything according to country. strange.. do you have any idea how can I change annotation settings?

Comment: @muru ehm. "This version does not conform to the POSIX standard" That I would consider a bug >:-D

Comment: @muru where did you find the comment btw?

Comment: @bensen see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bc.1.html (section DIFFERENCES).